# return to the previous version of polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia

The latest version of polyglossia is problematic. How to return to the previous one ?

Here is a MWA and it's log file.
Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\usepackage[quiet,nolocalmarks]{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
% \setotherlanguage{french}
% \setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
مرحبا.
\end{document}
```

Log file : [log file](https://pastebin.com/z54xibSy)

Comment: Please tell us which TeX distribution you employ. TeXLive, MikTeX, something else?

Comment: @Mico I am usinig TeXLive 2023 ... see the log file https://pastebin.com/z54xibSy

Comment: it is not directly polyglossia but l3kernel. See https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/626#issuecomment-1948132203 for a work-around. And the issue also says that an update is on-the-way to ctan.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Ulrike Fischer for the workaround : https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/626#issuecomment-1948132203

(The problem is not specific to polyglossia but l3kernel)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\usepackage[quiet,nolocalmarks]{polyglossia}


% work around a bug in polyglossia
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pretocmd\xpg@set@alias@values{%
    \prop_if_exist:cF { xpg@alias@keyvals@#1@#4 }
    { \prop_new:c {xpg@alias@keyvals@#1@#4} }
}{}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
% end of workaround

\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
% \setotherlanguage{french}
% \setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
مرحبا.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also: Previsouly, it was possible to load polyglossia before setting the normal font size. Now, (with the workaround) the normal font size must be set first. Not an issue for the ordinary document classes, which specify normal font size (or default) as class option.